# Azure AD B2C auth with username and e-mail

Tags: azure, configuration, cloud, azure-ad-b2c

I'm migrating all my users from a legacy IdP to the Azure AD B2C.
How can I configure the "Local account" to allow users to login with username OR e-mail?

It seems the Local Account just allows me to configure one of these options but I want to allow users to chose to login with e-mail or username.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this custom policy sample
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to provide an option for user to choose Email/Username, using custom policy you can acheive please refer this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email)

If you are looking to provide a was using built in [user flow policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows) You can add [Local identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-add-identity-providers) with email/username in the Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C).

For Migrating users identified using a local IdP to your B2C tenant refer this [document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/1/36187D50-A693-4547-848A-176F17AE1213/Deep%20Dive%20on%20Azure%20AD%20B2C%20Custom%20Policies/Azure%20AD%20B2C%20Custom%20Policies%20-%20Bring-your-own-identity%20and%20Migrating%20Users.pdf).

Comment: Ok, but for example, in this case, this configuration just allows me to create a Local account with one of these options. I want to allow users to chose to login with e-mail or username.

Comment: The question was about using either methods, the default Local Provider only allows for one method.

Comment: @ArielMoraes Thanks for correcting me. I have Updated my anser